# InDesign: Re-Link text frames to master page

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I need to ask for your help again ;)

I am working at a 200-page-Document for our high school graduation, which is going to be printed as a book and contains a page for each student with a photo and a short text about him. After I created these ~135 pages by hand, I need to insert a few pages for students who sent their texts later. I used a master page which contained next to graphical elements a text frame for the students' text, I edited that text frame on each page by creating a copy with ctrl+shift+click.

But when inserting a single page somewhere, each left page after that page gets a right page and each right page gets a left page. Every object (except the text frame) changes it's position regarding the master page left / right site, , but since the text frame is rotated -6,25° on left pages and 6,25° on right pages, the text frame keeps its original rotation and is now rotated -6,25° on right pages and 6,25° on left pages (see screenshots).

page 16 and 17 before inserting a page:
[image: page 16 and 17 before inserting a page]

page 16 and 17 after inserting a page after page 15:
[image: page 16 and 17 after inserting a page after page 15]

page 18 and 19 after inserting a page after page 15:
[image: page 18 and 19 after inserting a page after page 15]
and so on...

How can I get InDesign to understand that these textframes belong to their master frames and should be flipped as well when the pages change from left to right? Any help is much appreciated, since I don't want to edit each of these text frames by hand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unforunately not, because when resizing / moving the text field on the master page, these changes still get applied to its chield text fields on the individual pages.

Comment: I don't know why you mark my question as a duplicate, as I already said, resizing and moving the text frames IS still possible, so they are still linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InDesign has the ability to adjust content from the left margin set to the right margin set and vice versa as you add new pages, provided you have both a left and right master and each is set with respectively mirrored margins. Unfortunately, InDesign can't mirror the rotation angles of your frames, using master pages to accomplish this task is not going to work. However, there IS a solution: Thread all of the text together and use paragraph styles to shift the text for you as you add new content. You won't need to add a new page in the middle of the document, but at the end to catch the overset text. See below.


From the Paragraph styles pallet, create a new paragraph style called "Name" with the characteristics you want the name on each page to have. For this style, under "Keep Options" set "Start Paragraph" to "In Next Frame." Assign a shortcut to this style for later use. 
Next, create another new paragraph style with your desired body text characteristics. You don't need keep options for this style. Don't apply any of these styles yet. 
Next, you need to thread all of your text frames together. Select the very first of your angled text frames and then click on the open box link handle at the lower right corner. This will change your cursor to the link text frame icon. Next, click on the second angled frame. The text from the second frame will shift up and concatenate with the end of the text from frame one. Continue through your document in this fashion, linking each frame to the next until they are all linked. It may help to enable View>Extras>Show Text Threads while you work. You should end up with a long story consisting of name/body/name/body, etc.

Now select and apply the body paragraph style to ALL of the text I (including the names) in the thread. Next, starting at the beginning of the text, insert the cursor at the name line and apply the Name style using your shortcut. Move to the next name and apply the shortcut there as well. You should notice that this causes the name to appear at the top of the next frame. Keep applying the name style to the names until they are all set. 

Once that is done, whenever you need to add a new name, just paste in the text where you want it and apply the appropriate styles. Everything behind it will automatically shift toward the end of the book. Then add a last page to accommodate the expanded content and simply link the new frame.

I know this is a lot to take in, so let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood everything so far, will give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your help! worked very well, I think I'm just a bit too much into automation :D